# Can I actually attach single entity to multiple contexts

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In my custom developed application I got an error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker". It means as I understand that I cannot use the same entity attached to multiple contexts. To reproduce error I create a sandbox application with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace EntityFrameworkRepositoryPatternTestApp
{
  public class Item
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public double SomeDouble { get; set; }
  }

  public class Context : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ItemConfiguration());
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public Context() : base("Connection")
    {
    }
  }

  public class ItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
  {
    public ItemConfiguration()
    {
      this.ToTable("Items").HasKey(i => i.Id);
      this.Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
      this.Property(i => i.SomeString).HasMaxLength(255);
      this.Property(i => i.SomeInt);
      this.Property(i => i.SomeDouble);
    }
  }

  public interface IRepository<T>
  {
    T Add(T item);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
    T GetById(Guid id);
    void Remove(T item);
  }

  public class EntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
  {
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    private Context Context { get; }

    public TEntity Add(TEntity item)
    {
      this.dbSet.Add(item);
      return item;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
      IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.dbSet;
      if (filter != null)
        query = query.Where(filter);
      return query.ToList();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(Guid id)
    {
      return this.dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity item)
    {
      this.dbSet.Remove(item);
    }

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(Context context)
    {
      this.Context = context;
      this.dbSet = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
  }

  public interface IDomainContext
  {
    int SaveChanges();
    int SaveChangesWithoutClientValidation();
  }

  public interface IDomainContext<TEntity> : IDomainContext where TEntity : class
  {
    IRepository<TEntity> Entities { get; }

    void Update(TEntity item);
    void Attach(TEntity item);
    void Detach(TEntity item);
  }

  public class DomainContext<TEntity> : IDomainContext<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : class
  {
    private Context context;

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
      return this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> Entities => this.GetRepository<TEntity>();

    public void Update(TEntity item)
    {
      var entry = this.context.Entry(item);
      foreach (var propertyName in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
      {
        var original = entry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
        var current = entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
        if ((original == null && current != null) || 
            ((original != null) && !original.Equals(current)))
          entry.Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;
      }
    }

    public void Attach(TEntity item) =>
      this.context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(item);

    public void Detach(TEntity entity) =>
      ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this.context.Dispose();
    }

    private IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
      var resultRepository = new EntityFrameworkRepository<T>(this.context);
      return resultRepository;
    }

    public DomainContext()
    {
      this.context = new Context();
    }
  }

  public class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var domainContext = new DomainContext<Item>();
      {
        var item = new Item() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), SomeDouble = 666, SomeInt = 777, SomeString = "some string"};
        domainContext.Entities.Add(item);
        domainContext.SaveChanges();
        using (var domainContext2 = new DomainContext<Item>())
        {
          if (item != null)
          {
            domainContext2.Attach(item);
            item.SomeDouble = 11.28;
            domainContext2.Update(item);
            domainContext2.SaveChanges();
          }
        }
      }
      domainContext.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I don't actually get an error in this sandbox application. So now I need to understand, whether Entity Framework really forbids to attach single entity to multiple contexts and how to overcome this limitation. The solution I thought about was to create entity copy when attaching it to another context. But now I think, that it really is possible to attach entity to another context without creating a copy.

Comment: I think the key thing you're missing is that an entity can only be tracked by one context _at a given time_. You can set an entity's state to `EntityState.Detached` to stop it being tracked, then attach it to another context

Comment: Ok. But why I don't get error in the test application? It clearly shares one entity between two contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [EF proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592886%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can't be attached to multiple contexts because they have a reference to the context they were created in.

The statement...

```
var item = new Item() ...
```

...creates a simple POCO, which doesn't know anything about a context, not even when it's attached to one.

If you replace this by...

```
var item = context.Items.Create();
```

...`item` will be a proxy object and you'll notice that trying to attach it to another context will throw the "cannot be referenced by multiple instances" exception.

Also, when a context reads an object from the database it will be a proxy object (provided that all conditions for the entity class to become a proxy are met).

Comment: It seems reasonable, but when I replaced the string as you suggested I still didn't get an error...

Comment: It has to do with the conditions for creating a proxy. `Item` is a simple class without `virtual` navigation properties, so EF won't create a proxy. Proxies are mainly useful for lazy loading of navigation properties.

Comment: Yes, it really raises a desired exception when entity have virtual property containing child collection.